# Does a Verilog event control block execution of a procedure?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Does a Verilog event control block execution of a procedure till the event happens? Consider the example below.

```
module test;
  reg a;
  initial begin
    @(a) $display("%b", a);
    $display("the_message");
  end
endmodule
```

If I run the above, the simulation ends without `the_message` printed. Why?

Does this mean that `@(a)` blocks till `a` changes? If so, why doesn't the simulation hang forever instead of terminating without printing `the_message`?

Thanks

Comment: Just a little nit, but in (System)-Verilog we don't speak of procedures. There are tasks [can consume time, return no value, have zero or more arguments] and functions [cannot consume time, must return a value, have one or more arguments].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event driven simulators run until there are no more active events scheduled, or explicitly terminated (`$finish`).

Comment: thanks @dave_59, can you please recommend me a URL that discusses scheduling and event processing in a fair amount of detail?